# How do I fix my garage door opener that stops working in hot weather?

Tags: garage-door-opener

During hot weather, my garage door opener stops working.  Then it works OK when it cools in the evening.  Any ideas of how to fix?  Or what causes this hot weather stoppage?

Comment: Can you please define "stops working"?  Doesn't open? Doesn't close? Doesn't open or close? Makes a funny noise but doesn't open/close? Doesn't make any noise, or open/close?  Is the door opener new, old, or maybe recently repaired? How old is the door? When is the last time the door was serviced (inspected, lubed, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with a house and the root cause for me was sunlight interfering with the sensors.  It only happened in the summer for about 3 hours of the day when the sun was just right to overwhelm the light beam receiver.  My fix was a cardboard tube mounted around the receiver to provide addition sun light blocking so it could see the light emitter.  You can also try swapping the emitter and receiver.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may have something to do with the safety system.  My whacky idea:  The light beam on the safety system is slightly misaligned.  When the weather gets hot, the metal on the bracket and rails expands in a way such that the safety sensors become misaligned.  When it's hot and the door doesn't operate, check to see if there are any blinking lights on the sensors.  If lights are blinking, the sensors are misaligned, and need to be fixed.